# wsjar file error when starting Websphere 7 server using Java 6

Tags: java, websphere-7, runtimeexception, myeclipse

I'm trying to get a Java web application running on my local environment.  I'm using WebSphere 7.0 and MyEclipseBlue 10 using Java 6.  The app builds and deploys fine, but when I start up the server I receive this error:

> CWXRS0010W: Error while processing:
>   wsjar:file:/C:/Apps/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/M006Node02Cell/rbb3.ear/rb31.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar!/plugin.xml
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.ibm.wkplc.extensionregistry.Extension.equals(Extension.java:201)...

The odd part is that I had this application running before but didn't have this issue.

Does anyone have any advice on eliminating this error?  Does it even matter that it is there?  I will gladly provide more information if needed!

Thanks!

Comment: Remove `com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib`. You should never put any WebSphere jars in the `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Well now there's the interesting part because I don't have that jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder.  :/

Comment: Check the path: C:/Apps/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/7.0/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/M006Node02Cell/rbb3.ear/rb31.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar, maybe you same how put it there during application build.

Comment: Sure enough, it's in there.  Good find.  Any ideas how it could be getting there?

Comment: You probably using Maven build, which has incorrectly set dependencies.

Comment: I am not using Maven at all actually; my organization does not allow it.

Comment: Ok, so in that case verify deployment settings - right click your `rb31` project, select Properties > Deployment Assembly, check if you dont have that jar somewhere there. How you build your project?

Comment: I have two entries in the Web Deployment Assembly 1) /src (deploy path >> WEB-INF/classes) 2) /WebContent (deploy path >> /).

Comment: So you have to verify your build process, how `com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar` magically appears in WEB-INF/lib, if it is nowhere defined.

Comment: I did some more digging and found that a library that my organization has us put on our build path actually contained the com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar, so it was there but hidden!  I removed it and now that error is gone.  Thank you very much for your help.  If you summarize your comments in an answer below I will accept it as the correct answer for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include WebSphere related libraries in application itself. So in your case please remove `com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib`.

Check you Maven, Eclipse, or any other build process you are doing to create EAR, and make sure that such WebSphere jars are not added to the application.

Comment: Thanks Gas!  (Others:  Please see the above comment thread for more details on how this particular situation was resolved in case it is helpful.)